# for loop in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I just started with python..
I got an error with for loop..
What is the problem ??

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "userentry.py", line 34, in <module>
    userentry(p,i)
  File "userentry.py", line 26, in userentry
    for cl in len(mylist):
  TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Please help me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just iterate over the list, you don't iterate over the length of the list.

```
for cl in mylist:
    # do stuff
```

If you need to keep track of the index of the current item, use `enumerate`:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(mylist):
    # idx = index of current item
    # item = current item
```

When you try to do `for cl in len(mylist)`, that's like saying `for cl in 5` (if mylist has length of 5), which doesn't really make sense.  If you want to just iterate over the indices of a list, it's best to use the `enumerate` example above, but you can also do

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    # mylist[i] is the ith item in the list
```

Though there are very few reasons to do this instead of just using the `enumerate` version above.

Answer (score 0):

you should write

```
for cl in mylist:
```

len() is not iterable.

Comment: But it returns TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @Ria: cl is not the index.  It's the item itself.  Please use a `print` statement to see what value `cl` has.

Answer (score 0):

```
for cl in mylist:
    print repr(cl)
    #do whatever
```